# How to Debounce/Throttle Property changed using Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have been following a tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/omnibs/6b2cbdba2685693448ee6779736a00c2#throttle---simple) and they are using `IEnumerable<int>`  instead of using a collection how can I use a single values raised multiple times in milliseconds?

So when the user drags the slider the event gets raised many times a seconds how can I reduce the amount of command.

e.g The position value starts at 0.0 the user drags to 3000.56 in 100 milliseconds. How can I only print 0, then 3000.56, and ignore all in between. within the same motion if the user drag back to 2000.89 it should print 2000.89?

multiple controls raises this event so it should group by the Unique ID.

XMAL:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbilly" Text="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,382" ></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbob" Text="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,162,0,233" ></TextBox>
    <Slider x:Name="slbilly"  Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,57,0,306" MouseDown="slbilly_MouseDown" MouseUp="slbilly_MouseUp"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slbob"  Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,206,0,171" MouseDown="slbob_MouseDown" MouseUp="slbob_MouseUp"/>
</Grid>
```

Model:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ID;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }
        set
        {
            _ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ID"));
        }
    }
    private float _Position;
    public float Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _Position;
        }
        set
        {
            _Position = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Position"));
        }
    }
    public Student(string id, float position)
    {

        this.Position = position;
        this.ID = id;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
Student billy = new Student("Unique1", 0.0f);
Student Bob = new Student("Unique2", 0.0f);
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtbilly.DataContext = billy;
    slbilly.DataContext = billy;
    billy.PropertyChanged += Students_PropertyChanged;

    txtbob.DataContext = Bob;
    slbob.DataContext = Bob;
    Bob.PropertyChanged += Students_PropertyChanged;

}

private void Students_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // All values handles here
    var anyStudent = (Student)sender;
    Debug.Print(anyStudent.ID + " " + anyStudent.Position);

    var observable = anyStudent.Position.ToObservable().Timestamp();
    var throttled = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

    using (throttled.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Timestamp)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

private void slbob_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Start trottle
}

private void slbob_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //stop trottle
}

private void slbilly_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Start trottle
}

private void slbilly_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //stop trottle
}
```

> Error:
>
> Error CS1061  'float' does not contain a definition for 'ToObservable'
> and no accessible extension method 'ToObservable' accepting a first
> argument of type 'float' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why do you not simply increase the value for the `Throttle()` call you already have?

Comment: @Progman The Throttle above is giving an error attached to the question now.

Comment: `Position` is a `float`. You can't call `.ToObservable()` on a `float`.